# How to check my website against accessibility 508 complaint

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, accessibility, angularjs

I have an application with **WCF** and **.net** core as backend and **Angular JS** 1.8.2 as front end. I need to perform Accessibility check on my website to check if someone with Visual impairment can access the website with Ease. I already have ngAria module.

I know there are bunch of tools out there like Wave etc. I am looking for some more-open source tools to have accessibility compliant. Can someone please help me with finding that? I am doing this for first time.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.w3.org/WAI/test-evaluate/tools/list/  or https://www.powermapper.com/products/sortsite/checks/accessibility-checks/ if you are willing to pay